# Resize the QR code scanner section

Tags: ionic2, phonegap-plugins, qr-code

i am developing one android application in ionic 2 which needs **qr code scanning functionality** and to achieve this i am using this [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/02/add-barcode-scanning-functionality-to-your-ionic-2-app/)

**The Issue which am facing is:**
When i open the camera for scanning the QR code, it covers the complete screen of mobile.

**What I Want:**
I want to resize the QR code scan area like 250px * 250px.

Below is the code i am using in .html file

```
<button primary (click)="scan()">Scan</button>
```

And below is the code i am using in .ts file

```
import {Page, Platform, Alert, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'})
export class HomePage 
 {
static get parameters() {
    return [[Platform], [NavController]];
}

constructor(platform, navController) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.navController = navController;
}

scan() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan((result) => {
            this.nav.present(Alert.create({
                title: "Scan Results",
                subTitle: result.text,
                buttons: ["Close"]
            }));
        }, (error) => {
            this.nav.present(Alert.create({
                title: "Attention!",
                subTitle: error,
                buttons: ["Close"]
            }));
        });
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? you have to see some of your code.

Comment: @Philipp i added my piece of code to this question.